# Remove unwanted string from string

Tags: javascript

How can I remove a fixed string inside a string ?

For instance :

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa@localhost
bbb@localhost
ggggggg@localhost
```

I want to remove *@localhost* .I tried substring() method but while the start is the same the end isn't the same for those strings. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `newStr = str.split("@localhost")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use replace:.

```
var str = "ggggggg@localhost".replace('@localhost','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
yourString.replace("@localhost", "");
```

This will replace all occurrences of `@localhost` in your string with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"aaaaaaaaaaaa@localhost".replace("@localhost", "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
"ggggggg@localhost".replace("@localhost", "");
```